# Android отправка сообщения в viber, конкретному пользователю

Tags: java, android

Для отправки сообщения с выбором пользователя, работает все хорошо. Мой код

```
public void sendViberTo(String bodyText) {
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
   sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   sendIntent.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
   sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodyText);
   sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
   startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

но хотелось бы сделать отправку конкретному пользователю viber.

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("viber://chat?number=7900000000")))
```

Comment: в чат пользователя переходит, но текст не вставляется((

Comment: @ИгорьКозырев, вот такое советуют `viber://pa?chatURI=[public account URI]&text=[message text]`, попробуйте